# Collection view not displaying cells using custom object

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avfoundation, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making an app that lets you record a video, then save it to the documents directory and a `Post` object, along with a thumbnail image. When I record a video and tap "use video", I see my print statements that the video was saved to the documents directory, and to the post object. However when I go to my collection view, which is set to display the thumbnail images from `Post`, it's empty. This is the function that handles saving the video and appending the `Post` object:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var posts = [Post]()
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
        var uniqueVideoID = ""
        var videoURL:NSURL? = NSURL()
        var uniqueID = ""

        uniqueID = NSUUID().uuidString

        // Get the path as URL and store the data in myVideoVarData
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL as NSURL?
        let myVideoVarData = try! Data(contentsOf: videoURL! as URL)

        // Write data to temp diroctory
        let tempPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let tempDocumentsDirectory: AnyObject = tempPath[0] as AnyObject
        uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "TEMPVIDEO.MOV"
        let tempDataPath = tempDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
        try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath), options: [])

        //Getting the time value of the movie.
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDataPath)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fileURL)
        let duration : CMTime = asset.duration

        //Now we remove the data from the temp Document Diroctory.
        do{
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: tempDataPath)
        } catch {
            //Do nothing
        }

        // Check to see if video is under the 18500 (:30 seconds)
        if duration.value <= 18500 {

            // Write the data to the Document Directory for use later on
            let docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
            let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = docPaths[0] as AnyObject
            uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "VIDEO.MOV"
            let docDataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
            try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), options: [])
            print("docDataPath under picker ",docDataPath)
            print("Video saved to documents directory")

            //Create a thumbnail image from the video
            let assetImageGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            assetImageGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)

            //Add thumbnail & video path to Post object
            if let videoImage = try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) {
                let video = Post(pathToVideo: docDataPath, thumbnail: UIImage(cgImage: videoImage))
                posts.append(video)
                print("Video saved to Post object")
            }
        }else{
            print("Video not saved")
        }
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint I can see that `Post` does indeed have one value after the save, so I'm not sure why the CV isn't displaying the thumbnail.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    cell.postImage.image = posts[indexPath.row].thumbnail
    cell.postImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    return cell
}
```

Post Object:

```
class Post: NSObject {
var thumbnail: UIImage!
var pathToVideo: String!

init(pathToVideo: String, thumbnail: UIImage) {
    self.pathToVideo = pathToVideo
    self.thumbnail = thumbnail
}
}
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a singleton VideoFeedController? What are you trying to accomplish by doing this:

```
let feed = VideoFeedController()
feed.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

Seems to me you are reloading an instance of the VideoFeedController that is never displayed anywhere.

if your image picking function is within the VideoFeedController you could simply call

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

but if not, then you could try overriding viewDidAppear inside the VideoFeedController and reload the collectionView there, i.e. add this to the VideoFeedController

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `VideoFeedController` is separate from the `RecordVideoViewController` (where the save function is located). I removed `let feed = VideoFeedController()` and the reload from that function and instead put `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` of my `VideoFeedController`, however the collection view is still empty. I also tried putting the reload in a `viewWillAppear` to no avail.

Comment: I think jokeman is on the right path here, you need to make sure that the posts array in your VideoFeedController is being populated with the same objects as you put in your posts array in RecordVideoViewController. Having a posts array in both controllers does not mean that adding an object to one automatically adds it to the other as well, you need to connect them somehow. Just like adding a box of cereal to a shopping bag in your grocery store does not mean that it automatically gets added to another shopping bag at your home.